# How to do natural join when the common column have different names?

Tags: sql, natural-join

I need to do natural join on two tables named Customers and Addresses (relationship 1:1), the common column in those tables is the key- ID (according to that column the natural join will operate) . however- this Column in table Customer is called "ID_Customer", and in the table Addresses it's called- "ID".

Because of that, the natural join doesn't work correctly, because the program doesn't identify that it's the same column (by significance).

I can not change the columns names to be the same (because of many reasons..)
is there any way I could make this work- so the program would understand those are the same columns?

Comment: What is "the program"?

Comment: A natural join is an equi-join based on _columns with the same name_. If the columns don't have the same name, you can't have a natural join, by definition. Use a normal join. (And don't ever write "urgent" in your questions, especially not in the title, unless you're looking for negative attention.)

Comment: @Mat Natural join of two tables with no columns in common is defined & is cross join. The asker says it "won't work correctly" but what they mean is "won't give the answer I want".

Answer (score 7):

So don't use `natural join`.  Do an explicit `join` instead:

```
from Customer c join
     Address a
     on a.id = c.id_Customer
```

Also, I wouldn't be surprised if the actual join condition were:

```
     on a.id_Customer = c.id
```

(When using `id` as the primary key of tables, a good practice is to include the table name in the foregn reference.)

As a general rule, natural joins are a bad choice in the long term.  You might store such queries in stored procedures, triggers, or applications.  Then someone modifies the table structure -- adds, removes, or renames a column.  And, the code stops working.

I prefer to always use explicit joins.

Comment: This did the job for me, I had two tables Cities(code, name, state) and States (code, state) and I could match Cities(state) with States(code) perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Let us assume that Customer and Addresses schema is as follows:

```
Customer(ID_customer, name)
Addresses(ID, address)
```

then natural join query would be as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM (Customer AS Customer(ID, name) NATURAL JOIN Addresses);
```

This will perform the natural join as intended joining the ID attributes of both the tables.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT whatever FROM Customers C, Addresses A
WHERE C.ID_Customer = A.ID
```